# Guile Scheme GOOPS slot accessor is not a valid generic function error

Tags: scheme, guile

I'm learning Guile GOOPS. I have a problem with a slot accessor. The code below

```lisp
(use-modules (oop goops))

(define-class <person> ()
  (name #:init-keyword #:name
        #:accessor person-name))

(let ([p (make <person> #:name "Vlad")])
  (display (person-name p)))
```

Gives the error: oop/goops.scm:1585:2: #<procedure %person-name-procedure (s)> is not a valid generic function

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question is correct and it works fine. The `person-name` accessor name clashed with a defined above in my test file `person` record with the same accessor name.